# Can anyone help - I can't get a Testcontroller to route/display in my browers - zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, controller

can anyone help me with this ?

i'm following a zend framework tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOwSfKXKpZQ quickstart (2) I seem to have everything working ok and have craeted a new project called square and can acceess the index page ok  - "http://127.0.0.1:8888/square/".

I have also created a new controller called Test , but when i try and access it -  "http://127.0.0.1:8888/square/test" i get a 404 error ?? i've tried to solve this but cant seem to get anywhere ??

looks easy on the tutorial !

im using EasyPHP as my testing server.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've dropped your Zend project in the "square" directory, which will work for the index controller but other routes will not match.  The "/square/test" route is most likely looking for SquareController::testAction.

What I didn't see at the beginning of that youtube demo is where he set up the virtual host.  I'm not familiar with EasyPHP, so there might be an easier way to do it, but you can give your site a local name, we'll call it "square.local", and then you don't have to include the square prefix in the url.

VirtualHost Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName    square.local
    DocumentRoot  /path/to/www/square
</VirtualHost>
```

Also add square.local to your windows hosts file (C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost square.local
```

Now you can go to http://square.local to get to IndexController.  http://square.local/test to get to TestController, etc.

Comment: thanks, sems to be having loads of problems since i decided to use ZF ! ive put this in my httpd.conf file         
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName square.local 
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\New User\Desktop\index.html"
</VirtualHost>
I've pointed it at a html file on my desktop to test if i've done it correctly and ive put this in my windows host file                                                                
127.0.0.1: localhost square.local  but still can't get it to work ?? any idea where im going wrong ??

Comment: Jody, think i have sorted it now, followed your instructions , thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

To start: in `applications/configs/application.ini`, set

`resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1`

so that the 404 page can report what module/controller/action the system thinks is being requested.

Comment: thanks, it still just has the 404 error , but it did come up with an access denied dont have permissons but it never appeared again ??

Comment: just tried again come up with:Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: It looks like vhost issues, not ZF issues. Your investigation with @Jody looks to be the right way to go.

Comment: yes you are right, i think i have sorted now ? tahnsk for your help